# flatMap versus for expression

Tags: scala, dictionary

After reading this excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation) on for-expressions, I tried to convert my `flatMap` to a `for-expression`.

```
val results: List[String] = foo()
def getId: List[String] = List((json \ "_id").asOpt[String].getOrElse(""))
val xs: List[String] = results.flatMap( x => getId(Json.parse(x)))
```

Then, the for-expression.

```
val results: List[String] = foo()
def getId: List[String] = List((json \ "_id").asOpt[String].getOrElse(""))
val xs: List[String] = for { 
    r <- result
    getId(Json.parse(r))
}
```

I get a compile-time error that `<-` was expected on the `getId(...)` line, but found `}`.

What's wrong with my for expression?

Answer (score 2):

Your for-comprehension needs to bind the result of `getId` to a name, and `yield` that:

```
val xs: List[String] = for {
  r <- result
  x <- getId(Json.parse(r))
} yield x
```

Each line inside the for-comprehension needs to either bind the result of a monadic computation to a name using

```
x <- expr

// or, `_ <- expr` to run `expr` purely for its effects and ignore the result
```

or it needs to be a simple assignment such as

```
x = expr
```

Since `getId(Json.parse(r))` alone does neither, this is invalid.

Comment: ah, so `yield` is **always** required? In the case of map to for-expression, yield will return a List[...]. But for a flatMap to for-expression, yield will return a List[List[...]]?

Comment: `yield` is required if you want to get a value (as opposed to just side-effects.) I'm not sure where you got `List[List[...]]` from.