# Convert Curried Function from flatMap to for-expression

Tags: scala

I successfully implemented the following curried function using `flatMap`:

```
  def map3(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int], c: Option[Int])
(f: (Int, Int, Int) => Option[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    a.flatMap(x => b.flatMap(y => c.flatMap(z => f(x,y,z) ) ) )
  }
```

Example:

```
scala> map3(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3))( (x,y,z) => Some(x*y*z) )
res0: Option[Int] = Some(6)
```

However, when I tried to implement the same function with a `for expression`:

```
  def map3ForExpr(a: Option[Int], b: Option[Int], c: Option[Int])
(f: (Int, Int, Int) => Option[Int]): Option[Int] = {
    for { 
        x <- a
        y <- b
        z <- b
        f(x,y,z)
    }
  }
```

... the following compile-time error occurred:

> C:\Users\Kevin\Workspace\side-work>scalac
>   TestForComprehensionMap3.scala TestForComprehensionMap3.scala:13:
>   error: '<-' expected but '}' found.
>           }
>           ^

Based on reading this excellent [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation), it seems to me that my `map3ForExpr` is equivalent to my `map3` code.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin, you have to return something from the for-comprehension:

```
 for{
   x <- a
   y <- b
   z <- c
   out <- f(x, y, z)
 } yield out
```

That is, it needs to know what to `map` and `flatMap` over plus it needs a `yeild` expression to be able to return a value. Without the `yield` you'll wind up with a desugared `foreach`.

Also, to add that if you were to merely `yield` the `f(x, y, z)` instead of first unpacking it into `out` that you'd wind up with an `Option[Option[Int]]` which is not what you want.

Comment: @KevinMeredith More importantly, after reading that post you linked (very good post) and then looking at what I wrote, you understand why.

Comment: shouldn't that excellent post's `for-expression`, bullet point #1 be modified to include a `yield`? Example: `for {
  bound <- list
  out <- f(bound)
} yield out`

Comment: @KevinMeredith Hmm, let me check. If they're just using it for side-effects, no. If not, then it does need to be.

Comment: I asked my above question since the post lists `for { bound <- list; f(bound) }` as being equivalent to `list flatMap f`. [I'm aware you're looking into it, but I wanted to mention my reasoning]

Comment: @KevinMeredith I fixed the other post. It had an error just where you said.