# Scala for/yield syntax

Tags: scala, for-loop, yield

In the book that I'm studying there is an exercise:

> Write a loop that swaps adjacent elements of an array of integer. For example `Array(1,2,3,4,5)` becomes `Array(2,1,4,3,5)`. My solution is:

```
var v = Array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
for (i <- 0 until v.length by 2) {
  var temp = 0
  temp = v(i+1); v(i+1) = v(i); v(i) = temp
}
```

This algorithm works fine but isn't written fully exploiting the potential of Scala, it is written as if I wrote in C++. In fact, the following exercise asks:

Repeat the preceding assignment, but produce a new array with the swapped values. Use **for/yield**.

Now I tried with:

```
val a = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5)
var res = for (i <- 0 until a.length by 2) yield a(i)
for (i <- 1 until a.length by 2) res(i-1)=a(i) <---------eclipse give me an error
```

The error is: "**value update is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]**"

How can I solve this task? I understand that the syntax "for / yield" is very powerful, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: The error is because `res` is an immutable sequence (a Vector), which cannot be updated in-place. Vector does have an `updated(index: Int, elem: A)` method, however, which returns a new Vector with the updated element.

Comment: _a_ is an ArrayBuffer, so automatically also _res_ become an ArrayBuffer. Right?

Comment: No, it doesn't - try it and see! It would become an `ArrayBuffer` if you did something like `for (i <- a) yield i` where `a` is the starting collection in the for-comprehension.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `sliding` function that does exactly what you need:

```
(for {
  i <- Array(1,2,3,4,5).sliding(2,2)
  j <- i.reverse
} yield j).toArray
```

Comment: Or a one-liner but not for-loop:
`Array(1,2,3,4,5).sliding(2,2).flatMap(_.reverse).toArray`

Comment: Could you explain in detail the code you've written please? I understand the sliding function, but why two index (i and j)?

Comment: `i<- Array(1,2,3,4,5).sliding(2,2)`

spawns: `Array(Array(1, 2), Array(3, 4), Array(5))`

`i` iterate over inner Arrays. Now you need to reverse them and you need a name for it so you just give it a `j` as name.

To better understand for-comprehensions search on google how they are expanded. Those are really series of flatMap, map and filter.

Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation

Answer (score 1):

I am working through **Scala for the Impatient** myself to refresh my Scala coding skills. Given the concepts introduced by this point in the book, I believe the author is looking for the following:

```
val a = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
for (i <- 0 until a.length) 
  yield 
    if (i % 2 == 0) 
      if (i == a.length-1) a(i) 
      else a(i+1) 
    else a(i-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your generator, you use `0 until v.length by 2`, which is an `IndexedSeq`. This being your input type, `yield` will produce the same collection type for `res`.

Since `immutable.IndexedSeq` is immutable, you cannot modify it. Hence `res(i-1)=a(i)`, which would update the item at i-1, is not allowed.

So, one option would be to convert `res` to a mutable collection before you go on.

An often preferable option would be to solve it without updating. Here an [example](http://scalafiddle.net/console/c429429bf1f2af051f2021dc92a8ebea) using `foldLeft`, which iterates over our `IndexedSeq` and builds up a new, flattened `Array[Int]`

```
val array = Array(1,2,3,4,5)

val result = (
    for ( i <- 0 until array.length by 2) 
    yield 
        if (i < array.length-1) 
            Array(array(i+1), array(i)) 
        else 
            Array(array(i))
).foldLeft (Array[Int]()) ((a,b) => a ++ b )
```

Comment: This code work fine, like other codes posted by other users, but I don't really understand it yet. Can you explain me, please? The structure if()...else() after the yield determine the result value I think. But what about .foldLeft ?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about [folds](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold) from Haskell. Haskell is a functional language that is similar to Scala in ways. I suggest reading Haskell's description of folds because information on Haskell is easy to find in a nice, understandable format. I have a hard time with the information out there for Scala.

This way you might be able to get a general understanding of what it is folds do.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because `res` is an immutable sequence (a Vector), which cannot be updated in-place. Vector does have an `updated(index: Int, elem: A)` method, however, which returns a new Vector with the updated element.

I'm not sure what the writer of the exercise had in mind - using for/yield seems a little awkward here, but you could use `grouped()`:

```
val a = Array(1,2,3,4,5)            //> a  : Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

val swapped = (for (i <- a.grouped(2)) yield i.reverse).flatten.toArray            
                              //> swapped  : Array[Int] = Array(2, 1, 4, 3, 5)
```

A neater way without for/yield, using flatMap is also possible

```
a.grouped(2).toArray.flatMap(_.reverse)                                      
                                   //> res5: Array[Int] = Array(2, 1, 4, 3, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a new approach:

```
(for (i<-0 to arr.length-2 by 2) yield Array(arr(i+1), arr(i))).flatten.toArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
def swap(a: Array[Int]): Array[Int] = {
    for (elem <- 0 until a.length)
      yield {
        if (elem % 2 == 0) {
          if (elem == a.length - 1) a(elem)
          else a(elem + 1)
        }
        else a(elem - 1)
      }
  }.toArray
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = for(j<- 0 until (a.length,2);
i<- 1 to 0 by -1; 
if (j+i < a.length) )  
   yield a(j+i)
```