# Expression of type Seq[unit] does not conform to expected type Seq[DataFrame] in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

In my function, I am returning a `finalDF`, a sequence of data frames. In the loop shown below, map returns `Seq[DataFrame]` and it is being stored in `finalDF` to be able to return to the caller, but in some cases where there is further processing, I would like to store the filtered dataframe for each iteration and pass it to next loop.

How do I do it? If I try to assign it to some temp val, it throws and error that expression of type `Seq[unit]` does not conform to expected type `Seq[DataFrame]`.

```
var finalDF: Seq[DataFrame] =null

    for (i <- 0 until stop){
  finalDF=strataCount(i).map(x=> {
    df.filter(df(cols(i)) === x)

    //how to get the above data frame to pass on to the next computation?
    }
  )

}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful:

```
val finalDF: Seq[DataFrame] = (0 to stop).flatMap(i => strataCount(i).map(x => df.filter(df(cols(i)) === x))).toSeq
```

`flatMap` to flatten the `Seq(Seq)`.

`(0 to stop)` will loop from `0` to `stop`, `flatMap` will flatten `List`, Like:

```
scala> (0 to 20).flatMap(i => List(i))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
scala> (0 to 20).map(i => List(i)).flatten
res1: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20)
```

for two counters, maybe you can do it like:

```
(0 to stop).flatMap(j => {
 (0 to stop).flatMap(i => strataCount(i).map(x => df.filter(df(cols(i)) === x)))
}).toSeq
```

or try: `for yield`, see: [Scala for/yield syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756814/scala-for-yield-syntax)

Comment: thanks, this has been really helpful , if you don't mind, can you please explain this syntax please? And one another thing, I would like to apply another loop for all the values in sequence finalDF, is it possible to specify two counters here? Thanks