# For comprehension without calling flatmap

Tags: scala

Is there a more idiomatic way of writing repeated calls to map (without using flatMap)?

Please see the following example:

```
val futureJson : Future[Seq[JsValue]] = futureBlogList.map(
                                            blogList => blogList.map(
                                                    blog => Json.obj("id" -> blog.id, "title" -> blog.title)))

val futureResult : Future[Result] = futureJson.map(jsList => Ok(JsArray(jsList)))
```

This is a function in Play which needs to return in this case a Future[Result].

I have tried using "for comprehension" but have not found an application for **flatMap**. My attempt using flatMap leaves me with Future[Nothing].

```
val futureJson : Future[Nothing] = for {
  blogList : Seq[Blog] <- futureBlogList
  blog : Blog       <- blogList
} yield {
  Json.obj("id" -> blog.id, "title" -> blog.title)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can't you use the *for comprehension* using an identity function inside the `yield` block (I've not the time to try it at the moment)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A for comprehension is always a combination of a number of `flatMaps`
  and one `map` function.
- The functions on the right side of the arrow in a for
  comprehension, always have the same result type (`Seq[...]`, `Option[...]`, ...)

Your working solution consists of two `map`s and a `Future` and a `Seq` so it cannot be converted into a for comprehension (nicely).

More information about for comprehensions (and the conversion with `flatMap/map`) can be found in [*Programming in Scala, 1ed*](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/for-expressions-revisited.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation?rq=1).

---

If you realy want to use a for comprehensions instead of the two `map`s, we can (as an educational exercise) convert the first `map` into a `flatMap`. The function using the `blogList` should then return a `Future`:

```
futureBlogList.flatMap(blogList =>
  Future.successful(
    blogList.map(blog => Json.obj("id" -> blog.id, "title" -> blog.title))
  )
)
```

We can convert the second `map` to a for expression:

```
futureBlogList.flatMap(blogList =>
  Future.successful(
    for (blog <- blogList) yield Json.obj("id" -> blog.id, "title" -> blog.title)
  )
)
//.map(identity)
```

Which we can turn into the following (pretty ugly) for comprehension:

```
for {
  blogList <- futureBlogList
  jsonBlogs <- Future.successful(
    for (blog <- blogList) yield Json.obj("id" -> blog.id, "title" -> blog.title)
  )
) yield jsonBlogs
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason your *for-comprehension* fails is that it has work on containers of the same type. In your example you are mixing a `Future` with a collection. *True*, both have `map` but they are different types of containers and therefore their `map`/`flatmap` chains cannot interoperate and hence cannot be used together in a *for-comprehension*. If you unrolled the *for-comprehension* you would get

```
futurBlogList.flatMap { blogList =>
  blogList.map { blog =>
    Json.obj("id" -> blog.id, "title" -> blog.title)
  }
}
```

The `flatMap` expects the result to be a `Future[U]` but the `map` call inside returns a `Seq[JSList]` instead.

The end result is that your nesting of two different types of `map` is the most idiomatic way to express the construct. At best you could combine the two calls into something like this:

```
val futureResult : Future[Result] = futureBlogList.map { blogList =>
  Ok(JsArray(
    blogList.map( blog => Json.obj("id" -> blog.id, "title" -> blog.title))
  ))
}
```