# How flatMap in a Map works in scala?

Tags: scala, dictionary, flatmap

This is my code

```
def testMap() = {
    val x = Map(
      1 -> Map(
        2 -> 3,
        3 -> 4
      ),
      5 -> Map(
        6 -> 7,
        7 -> 8
      )
    )

    for {
      (a, v) <- x
      (b, c) <- v
    } yield {
      a
    }
  }
```

The code above gives

```
List(1, 1, 5, 5)
```

If I change the yield value of the for comprehension `a` to `(a, b)`, the result is

```
Map(1 -> 3, 5 -> 7)
```

If I change `(a, b)` to `(a, b, c)`, the result is

```
List((1,2,3), (1,3,4), (5,6,7), (5,7,8))
```

My question is what is the mechanism behind the determination of the result type in this for comprehension?

Comment: It tries to match the original type. When you return pairs, you end up with a map, otherwise if can't make a map, so you get a List.

Comment: Can you explain by the code and the compiler behavior ?

Comment: I thought I just did :) If you start with `Map`,  and yield pairs, you end up with a `Map`. Otherwise, you get a `List` of whatever type you yield. What exactly is still unclear?

Comment: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html

Comment: If you want to desugar  code see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9892350/651140 `scala -print file.scala`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14602182/409976.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look into the API Documentation into the details of the map-Method you will find, that it has a second, implicit parameter of type `CanBuildFrom`.
An instance of `CanBuildFrom` from defines how a certain collection is build when mapping over some other collection and a certain element type is provided.

In the case where you get a Map as result, you are mapping over a Map and are providing binary tuples. So the compiler searches for a `CanBuildFrom`-instance, that can handle that.

To find such an instance, the compiler looks in different places, e.g. the current scope, the class a method is invoked on and its companion object.
In this case it will find an implicit field called `canBuildFrom` in the companion object of `Map` that is suitable and can be used to build a `Map` as result. So it tries to infer the result type to `Map` and as this succeeds uses this instance.

In the case, where you provide single values or triples instead, the instance found in the companion of `Map` does not have the required type, so it continues searching up the inheritance tree. It finds it in the companion object of `Iterable`. The instance their allows to build an `Iterable` of an arbitrary element type. So the compiler uses that.

So why do you get a `List`? Because that happens to be the implementation used there, the type system only guarantees you an `Iterable`.

If you want to get an `Iterable` instead of a `Map` you can provide a `CanBuildFrom` instance explicitly (only if you call map and flatMap directly) or just force the return type. There you will also notice that you won't be able to request a `List` even though you get one.

This wont work:

```
val l: List[Int] = Map(1->2).map(x=>3)
```

This however will:

```
val l: Iterable[Int] = Map(1->2).map(x=>3)
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to @dth, if you want a list, you can do:

```
val l = Map(1->2,3->4).view.map( ... ).toList
```

Here the map function apply on a lazy `IterableView`, which output also an `IterableView`, and the actual construction is triggered by the `toList`.

Note: Also, not using `view` can result in a dangerous behavior. Example:

```
val m = Map(2->2,3->3)

val l = m.map{ case (k,v) => (k/2,v) ).toList
// List((1,3))

val l = m.view.map{ case (k,v) => (k/2,v) ).toList
// List((1,2), (1,3))
```

Here, omitting the `.view` make the map output a Map which overrides duplicate keys (and does additional and unnecessary work).