# Scala: Using a value from an array to search in another array

Tags: arrays, scala

I have two arrays:

`GlobalArray:Array(Int,Array[String])` and `SpecificArray:Array(Int,Int)`.

The first `Int` in both of them is a key and I would like to get the element corresponding to that key from the `GlobalArray`.

In pseudocode:

```
val v1
For each element of SpecificArray
    Get the corresponding element from GlobalArray to use its Array[String]
         If (sum <= 100)
             for each String of the Array
                 update v1 
                 // ... some calculation
                 sum += 1

println (v1)
```

I know using `.map()` I could go through each position of the `SpecificArray`, but so far I was able to do this:

```
SpecificArray.map{x => val in_global = GlobalArray.filter(e => (e._1 == x._1))
                       // I don't know how to follow
                  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like below, I would prefer to `for` comprehension code which has better readability.

```
var sum:Int = 0
var result:String = ""
for {
  (k1,v1) <- SpecificArray //v1 is the second int from specific array
  (k2,values) <- GlobalArray if k1 == k2  //values is the second array from global array
  value  <- values if sum < 100  //value is one value frome the values
   _ = {sum+=1; result += s"(${v1}=${value})"} //Update something here with the v1 and value
 } yield ()

println(result)
```

Comment: Could I use this on SpecificArray and GlobalArray with different number of elements?

Comment: This way is the most readable for me, but how about performance? Is there any difference between using for or flatMap? Now I'm doing local tests but I have to use a cluster to run this.

Comment: The for comprehension is a syntax short cut for flatmap and map. Here is a good discussion about it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation

Answer (score 1):

How `sum` affects the logic and what exactly is `v1` is not clear from your code, but it looks like you do search through `GlobalArray` many times. If this is so, it makes sense to convert this array into a more search-friendly data structure: `Map`. You can do it like this

```
val globalMap = GlobalArray.toMap
```

and then you may use to join the strings like this

```
println(SpecificArray.flatMap({case (k,v) => globalMap(k).map(s => (k,v,s))}).toList)
```

If all you need is strings you may use just

```
println(SpecificArray.flatMap({case (k,v) => globalMap(k)}).toList)
```

Note that this code assumes that for every key in the `SpecificArray` there will be a matching key in the `GlobalArray`. If this is not the case, you should use some other method to access the `Map` like `getOrElse`:

```
println(SpecificArray.flatMap({case (k,v) => globalMap.getOrElse(k, Array()).map(s => (k,v,s))}).toList)
```

**Update**

If `sum` is actually `count` and it works for whole "joined" data rather than for each key in the `SpecificArray`, you may use `take` instead of it. Code would go like this:

```
val joined = SpecificArray2.flatMap({case (k,v) => globalMap.getOrElse(k, Array()).map(s => (s,v))})
        .take(100) // use take instead of sum
```

And then you may use `joined` whatever way you want. And updated demo that builds `v1` as joined string of form `v1 += String_of_GlobalArray + " = " + 2nd_Int_of_SpecificArray` is [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7kG5WQHsSvSH1u6ab8DhQw). The idea is to use `mkString` instead of explicit variable update.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I put `sum` because if it get 100 I don't need to continue. And `v1` is a variable which I want to update, for instance: `v1 = String_of_GlobalArray + " = " + 2nd_Int_of_SpecificArray` (or passing these values to a function). So, I need a value from each one.

Comment: @diens, I updated my answer to be closer to what it seems you want. Also take a look at the updated demo,

Answer (score 1):

**Note** needs more optimization

Convert GlobalArray to `Map` for faster lookup.

```
val GlobalMap = GlobalArray.toMap

SpecificArray.flatMap(x => GlobalMap(x._1))
.foldLeft(0)((sum:Int, s:String) => {
    if(sum<=100) {
    // update v1
    // some calculation
    }
    sum+1
})
```

If not all keys of `SpecificArray` is present in `GlobalMap` then use `GlobalMap.getOrElse(x._1, Array())`

Comment: Wow, thank you for your answer. Sorry, but I'm still stuck when I have to update `v1` because I need to use the second `Int` value from `SpecificArray` mixed with the `s` parameter.

Comment: Mutation (updates to variable) is discouraged in scala. Can you give more details about the purpose of `v1`

Comment: `v1` is a result to apply a function using the second `Int` value from `SpecificArray` and each `String` of the Array (the second field of `GlobalArray`)