# Inverting a map in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

I'm doing a course in Coursera about Scala functional programming. I'm in the 6th week.

I have the following code:

```
/* define the map of numbers to letters */ 
val nmem = Map(
  '2' -> "ABC", '3' -> "DEF", '4' -> "GHI", '5' -> "JKL", 
  '6' -> "MNO", '7' -> "PQRS", '8' -> "TUV", '9' -> "WXYZ"
)

/* invert the map to get a map of letters to digits */
val charCode: Map[Char, Char] = 
  for {
       (digit, str) <- nmem
       ltr <- str
  } yield ltr -> digit
```

My question is how does the for-comprehension work? `nmem` introduces the key (char) and the value (string) into digit and str. And later we have: ltr <- str which I don't know how it works because I don't understand how the program knows that ltr is a char instead of an string.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: thats like a nested for loop in imperative programming.

Comment: When you call `map` method on string, string is treated like sequence of chars. This second `<-` is the same to `map` method call.

Comment: Answers to  [Confused with the for-comprehension to flatMap/Map transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation) might be useful, but doesn't look like a 100% duplicate, if you look at it closely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `for`-comprehension is desugared into

```
nmem.flatMap { case (digit, str) => str.map { ltr => (ltr, digit) } }
```

Since `nmem` has type `Map[Char, String]`, the compiler knows that `(digit, str)` must be of type `(Char, String)`. Thus, it knows that `str` is of type `String`. The elements of a `String` are of type `Char`, thus the type of `ltr` is inferred to be `Char`.

If you wanted to write down all the gory details of the type inference, you would get something like this:

```
nmem.flatMap[(Char, Char), Map[Char, Char]]{ 
  case (digit: Char, str: String) => 
  str.map[(Char, Char), Seq[(Char, Char)]]{ 
    (ltr: Char) => (ltr, digit) 
  } 
}
```

Fortunately, this is not necessary, because all those types can be inferred automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand now how it works.
Nevertheless if we create this new method:

 /* define a function that returns the numbers of a given word */
  def wordCode(word: String): String = word map charCode
  wordCode("JAVA")

How is possible it works if we are passing a String to a charCode? This code return a String instead a map.

Comment: Are we using now charCode like a map method?

Comment: @zamora14 There are no `String`s passed to `charCode`. Since you invoke `map` on a `String`, the elements of the `String` (that is, characters of type `Char`) are passed to `charCode` one by one.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `item <- collection` is commonly used to iterate through each item in a collection.

A simple example would be:

```
for(mapping <- map){
   println(mapping)
}
```

In your case, this is essentially a nested `for` loop using yield syntax.

By default it will create a `List` and accumulate all the items.

Written with a bit more syntax may help:

```
val charCode : Map[Char,Char] = {  // Cast our result to a Map of (Char, Char)
    for ((digit, str) <- nmem;     // for every key-value pair (Char, String) in nmem
         ltr <- str)               // for every ltr (Char) in str (String)
    yield ltr -> digit             // add a new mapping to the map
}
```

You can check out [https://docs.scala-lang.org/../for-comprehensions.html](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) for more details

Answer (score -1):

The first one actually **`(digit, str) <- nmem`**, gets one tuple from Map[String, String], and next one **`ltr <- str`** gets chars from that string.