# What is the meaning of this snippet of code?

Tags: scala, for-loop, generator, for-comprehension

I am studying Scala language and I do not understand this piece of code:

```scala
for {
  i <- Set(2,3)
  j <- 1 to i
  k <- i to 2 by -1
} yield (j,k)
```

What does it mean that `j` is a Range from `1 to i` when `i` is a `Set`?

Comment: `i` isn't a `Set`. It is an element from the set, i.e. `2` or `3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you read the Scala documentation about for-comprehension and/or this answer on SO: [Confused with the for-comprehension to flatMap/Map transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14598990/confused-with-the-for-comprehension-to-flatmap-map-transformation)

The code you provided is strictly equivalent to the following one:

```scala
Set(2,3)
  .flatMap { i => 
    (1 to i).flatMap { j =>
      (i to 2 by -1).map { k =>
        (j,k)
      }
    }
  }
```

This way, you should see better that `i` is an "item" from the Set.